# Is there any way to output the earliest time/date per day a user has logged in?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to output the earliest time/date the user has logged in, but I want it per day. I can now output the earliest time/date a user has logged in but it's not on a daily basis. This query only works by showing me the earliest date/time a user has logged in, it does not take into account the date, it just outputs the earliest time/date the user has logged in. Sorry for the bad english. I hope someone can help me. Thank you so much!

By the way, here's the code:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "september-system";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT User_ID, MIN(Time) FROM records GROUP BY User_ID ORDER BY User_ID, MIN(Time) DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
 echo "<table><tr><th>User ID</th><th>Date/Time</th></tr>";
 // output data of each row
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<tr><td>" . $row["User_ID"]. "</td><td>" . $row["MIN(Time)"]. " </td></tr>";
 }
 echo "</table>";
} else {
 echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just group by both the user and the date:

```
SELECT User_ID, DATE(Time) as theday, MIN(Time)
FROM records
GROUP BY User_ID, DATE(Time)
ORDER BY User_ID, MIN(Time) DESC;
```

Note that `SELECT DISTINCT` is almost never appropriate with `GROUP BY`.  If you are learning SQL, then just use `GROUP BY` and don't bother with `SELECT DISTINCT` until you are more comfortable with the language.

Comment: I think that I need to use the `SELECT DISTINCT` in order to output only one earliest date/time per user(?) I'm sorry, I'm new to PHP and MySQL

Comment: @JopethDeza . . . The way your question is phrased, it suggests that you want the earliest time for each user on each day.  If you have a different question, then ask as *another* question, along with sample data and desired results.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. I'll try the one you suggested earlier. Sorry if I'm not making any sense, anyway thanks for the response.